# UITabBarItem action giving NSException

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a custom UITabBar with 4 UITabBarItems as given below.

[image]

[image]

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
class BaseItemViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate{

@IBOutlet var customTabBar: UITabBar!
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.customTabBar.delegate = self
```

custom function:

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        if item.tag == 0 {
            print("Tag one")
        } else if item.tag == 1 {
            print("Tag two")
        } else if item.tag == 2 {
            print("Tag three")
        } else if item.tag == 3 {
            print("Tag four")
        } 
    }
```

I need to do an action once I click on the tab bar item. I have added tags to the UIBarButtonItems but when I run the app, there is an error in the following line in the appDelegate file.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

saying

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Also the console prints the following:

> 2017-03-03 18:25:41.318 xxxxxx[1667:706023] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key NearbyHotelsButton.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x010f8494 **exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00bb9e02 objc_exception_throw + 50  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x010f80b1 -[NSException raise] + 17  3   Foundation
>
>   0x0084b7f8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] +
>   282   4   Foundation                          0x007a5e6a
>   _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115   5   Foundation                          0x007a5def -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 295     6
>
>   UIKit                               0x01d1c931 -[UIViewController
>   setValue:forKey:] + 85    7   Foundation
>
>   0x007da54b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 384   8
>   UIKit                               0x01f99a62
>   -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 132    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bce00c -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62    10  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01021131 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273   11  UIKit
>
>   0x01f980fc -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102  12  UIKit
>
>   0x01d24380 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 429    13
>   UIKit                               0x01d24db8 -[UIViewController
>   loadView] + 189   14  UIKit                               0x01d251c4
>   -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 154  15  UIKit                               0x01d2bcca -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 114  16  UIKit
>
>   0x01d4ee45
>   -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 202  17  UIKit
>
>   0x01d61258 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1389
>     18  UIKit                               0x01d7302d
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 803     19  UIKit                               0x01d7439e
>   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68   20  UIKit                               0x01f594b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252    21  UIKit
>
>   0x01c253d4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
>     22  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bce059 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:] + 70     23  QuartzCore
>
>   0x07ac7096 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144   24  QuartzCore
>
>   0x07aba8b6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388    25
>   QuartzCore                          0x07aba71a
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26    26  QuartzCore                          0x07aacee7
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317   27  QuartzCore                          0x07ae1847
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561    28  QuartzCore                          0x07ae30b8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 50    29  UIKit
>
>   0x01b86f55 _afterCACommitHandler + 197    30  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0100a75e
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0100a6be __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 398     32  CoreFoundation                      0x0100003c __CFRunLoopRun + 1340    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00fff846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470   34  CoreFoundation
>   0x00fff65b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   35  GraphicsServices
>   0x04308664 GSEventRunModal + 192  36  GraphicsServices
>   0x043084a1 GSEventRun + 104   37  UIKit
>   0x01b54eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160    38  Voyate
>   0x000d6681 main + 145     39  libdyld.dylib
>   0x04b20a25 start + 1  40  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

I tried this using a similar example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455763/uitabbaritem-action-not-working). Why is this error coming?

Comment: problem not in here , problem is on your button check this button `NearbyHotelsButton` are you used or  not'

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not problem  action. This is problem loading viewcontroller from storyboard. You have **IBOutlet** with name **NearbyHotelsButton**. But you viewcontroller does not have this property.

Comment: removed the referencing outlet to `NearbyHotelsButton` which was residue. And it worked. thanks!